# Multiply a 3D matrix with a 2D matrix, return a matrix with the same dimensions as the 2D one

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

In Numpy, say I have a matrix A of dimensions i x j x k, and a matrix B of dimensions k x i. How do I get back a product with dimensions k x i without using a loop?
For example:

```
 Let         A = [[[1 2],
                   [3 4]],
                  [[5 6],
                   [7 8]]]

             B = [[a b],
                  [c d]]
```

I would like to get:

```
             C = [[a+2c  5b+6d],
                  [3a+4c 7b+8d]]
```

My current solution is

```
np.diagonal(np.dot(A, B), axis1=0, axis2=2)
```

However, the problem is I'm working with a large data set (`A` and `B` have huge dimensions) so `np.dot(A, B)` would lead to `MemoryError`. Therefore I want to figure out a better way to solve this without computing the dot product.

I have looked into functions like `einsum` and `tensordot` but I didn't find what I need (or maybe I missed something). I would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: J has to figure in the output shape. Please show an example that's not 2x2 to see why.

Comment: `np.diagonal(np.dot(A, B), axis1=0, axis2=2)` doesn't seem to give the expected output. Check for `B= [[1,2],[3,4]]`, the expected output is `[[5,39],[11,53]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by analyzing the input and output dimensions.

```
A.shape -> i, j, k
B.shape -> k, i
```

Your example is not very good, but if you look carefully at what you're asking the output to be, the shape of `B` must match the first and last dimensions of `A`.

The sum reduction is happening along the last axis of `A` and the first axis of `B`:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', A, B)
```

`einsum` can be intimidating, but doing this sort of analysis can save you a lot of the frustration caused by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your output, `C[:,0]` is

```
A[0] @ B[0].T
```

and similarly, `C[:,1]` is `A[1] @ B[1].T`.

With that in mind, the `np.einsum` formula is:

```
C = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ji', A,B)
```

Comment: Beat you by 30 sec :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist haha, but your formula is different :-). I hate it when examples are like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's `ik` rather than `ki` for `B`?

Comment: I know, right. And no attempt from OP. I'm always half tempted to just close as unclear offhand.

Comment: pfff. beat me to it  :( `np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji',A,B)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's `ki`, or you can add `B.T` instead of `B` in the einsum.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Mine matches the expected output, but not the description on the first line (which I missed). Yours matched the description, and the output of OP's  solution.

Comment: I just kept BSing what the dimensions looked like until I got to the end. Then I wrote it down :)

Comment: Sorry about the bad example guys! I just tried and 'ki' worked as desired. I've stayed up all night and I'm too drowsy for a better example right now I'll edit the question tomorrow :-) Thank you so much for the help~